# which jar has com.google.common.event.disuptor.EventDisruptor?

Tags: disruptor-pattern

I got a project source that has com.google.common.event.disuptor.EventDisruptor,but I cannot found something about this.Is this from the disuptor?

```
import com.google.common.domain.message.DomainEventHandler;
import com.google.common.event.disuptor.EventDisruptor;
....
@Consumer("receivePayOrderState")
public class ReceivePayOrderState implements DomainEventHandler {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceivePayOrderState.class);
    private final Logger biLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("sms_order_bi");
    private int maxOrderMoney;

    @Override
    public void onEvent(EventDisruptor event, boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception {
        PayOrder payOrder = (PayOrder) event.getDomainMessage().getEventSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any of [these](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=com.google.common.event.disuptor.EventDisruptor)? Also, if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, `Ctrl+Shift+T` and typing `EventDisruptor` should give you that information.

Comment: Or look [here](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22disruptor%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes from the disruptor are under `com.lmax.disruptor`. So not its not part of the disruptor. Versions 2.7 to 2.10 were hosted on google code and were published with a maven group id of `com.googlecode.disruptor`however the actual packages were `com.lmax.disruptor`.

Poking around grepcode as suggested by S.R.I it looks like the [jdonframework](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jdon/jdonframework/6.6.4/com/jdon/async/disruptor/EventDisruptor.java#EventDisruptor) is your answer

Comment: thx.I have found it out.the package name that cannot be search by google was wrote by somebody.He encapsule com.lmax.disruptor,and package it to a jar file without source.